# How to get info on a process's virtual memory mappings in C (MacOS)

Tags: c, macos, macos-catalina

I want to get information on the virtual memory layout of a process (stack, libc, heap, and code) for my current process in C (MacOS).

I read that in Linux you can do this by looking at `/proc/<pid>/maps` and that you can do this on the MacOS command line via the `vmmap` command line utility.

How can I do this in C? If possible I would like to get all pages in the virtual memory space pertaining to my process.

Comment: You can use the proc_pidinfo() function like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74710092/498804

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `mach_vm_region_info` APIs to query this information from C. Here is an example from [Jonathan Levin's book MacOS and iOS Internals](http://www.newosxbook.com/src.jl?tree=listings&file=12-1-vmmap.c):

```
#include <mach/vm_map.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <mach-o/dyld_images.h>

/**
 * vmmap(1) clone for OS X and iOS
 * -------------------------------
 *
 * This is a simple example of using the mach_vm_region_info APIs in order to 
 * obtain a process' (technically, a task's) virtual memory address space, in a
 * manner akin to /proc/[pid]/maps on Linux.
 *
 * The process is simple - get the task port, then call mach_vm_region_info until
 * you've exhausted the address space (in iOS this happens around 0x40000000, 
 * where the commpage is). On iOS 6, for some peculiar reason the task port is
 * invalidated after each call, so the quick workaround here solves the problem
 * by regetting the port. The actual mach error code to check for is in the header
 * files, though the code simply tries regetting.
 *
 * N.B - For this code to work, you MUST provide the entitlements to allow 
 * task-for-pid to work, else you'll fail with error 5. The entitlements are in 
 * the output in Chapter 3, but for those of you who haven't bought the book, it would be:
 *
--- Cut here 

<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>com.apple.springboard.debugapplications</key>
        <true/>
        <key>get-task-allow</key>
        <true/>
        <key>proc_info-allow</key>
        <true/>
        <key>task_for_pid-allow</key>
        <true/>
        <key>run-unsigned-code</key>
        <true/>
</dict>
</plist>

--- Ok, enough :-)
 *
 *  so - copy the above XML to a file, say, "ent.xml", and be sure to run "ldid -Sent.xml vmmap"
 *  before trying to run this. You can download the binary (already thus signed) if you're lazy
 *  (and trust me, because you *will* need root on your i-Device for this)
 *
 *  As the book clearly states, once you have the task port, the world is your oyster. You can
 *  control the entire virtual memory space, reading and writing it as you please. Stay tuned
 *  for the corrupt tool (which will be provided soon in binary form)
 *
 */

int g_pid = 0; // required in iOS 6 (read below)

 /* 03/08/13 - Added List of Mach-O images: */


struct dyld_image_info *g_dii = NULL;
int     g_imageCount;

unsigned char *
readProcessMemory (int pid, mach_vm_address_t addr, mach_msg_type_number_t *size)
{
    // Helper function to read process memory (a la Win32 API of same name)
    // To make it easier for inclusion elsewhere, it takes a pid, and
    // does the task_for_pid by itself. Given that iOS invalidates task ports
    // after use, it's actually a good idea, since we'd need to reget anyway

    task_t  t;
    task_for_pid(mach_task_self(),pid, &t);
        mach_msg_type_number_t  dataCnt = size;
        vm_offset_t readMem;

    // Use vm_read, rather than mach_vm_read, since the latter is different
    // in iOS.

        kern_return_t kr = vm_read(t,        // vm_map_t target_task,
                     addr,     // mach_vm_address_t address,
                     *size,     // mach_vm_size_t size
                     &readMem,     //vm_offset_t *data,
                     size);     // mach_msg_type_number_t *dataCnt

        if (kr) {
                // DANG..
                fprintf (stderr, "Unable to read target task's memory @%p - kr 0x%x\n" , addr, kr);
                 return NULL;
                }

    return ( (unsigned char *) readMem);

}



kern_return_t mach_vm_read (vm_map_t, mach_vm_address_t, mach_vm_size_t, vm_offset_t *, mach_msg_type_number_t *);
void 
findListOfBinaries(task_t  t, mach_vm_address_t    addr, int size)
{


        kern_return_t kr;
        mach_msg_type_number_t  dataCnt = size;

    unsigned char *readData = readProcessMemory (g_pid, addr, &dataCnt);

    int machsig = 0xfeedface;

    // Checking only 0xfeedfa is a simple way to catch both 64-bit (facf) and 32-bit (face) headers
        // Machine endianness is automatically taken care of, too..

    if (readData && memcmp (readData + 1, ((unsigned char *) &machsig) + 1 , 3) == 0)
    {
        // This is a Mach header
        int i = 0;


        // A MUCH better way would be to iterate through the LC and find the name of dyld
        // but this would require my machlib.c (closed source) and really get the same result.
        // This works because on both iOS and OS X dyld is at /usr/lib.

        for (i = 0; i <dataCnt; i++)
        {
            if (memcmp(readData+i, "lib/dyld", 8) == 0)
            {
                unsigned int dyld_all_image_infos_offset ;
                int imageCount = 0;

                memcpy (&dyld_all_image_infos_offset, readData+DYLD_ALL_IMAGE_INFOS_OFFSET_OFFSET, sizeof (unsigned int));


                 struct dyld_all_image_infos *dyldaii ;
                 // Safeguard: should check that dyld_all_image_infos_offset is < size..

                if (dyld_all_image_infos_offset > size)
                {
                    // This is to be expected, since the dyld_all_image_infos is in a data region

                    //printf ("Offset %x is greater than region size : %x\n", dyld_all_image_infos_offset, size);
                    dataCnt = sizeof(dyld_all_image_infos);
                    readData = readProcessMemory (g_pid, addr + dyld_all_image_infos_offset , &dataCnt);

                    if (!readData) { return;}
                    dyldaii = (struct dyld_all_image_infos *) readData;

                }
                else
                {
                    dyldaii = (struct dyld_all_image_infos *) (readData +dyld_all_image_infos_offset);
                }


                printf ("Version: %d, %d images at offset %p\n",
                        dyldaii->version, dyldaii->infoArrayCount, dyldaii->infoArray);

                // Go to dyldaii->infoArray address

                imageCount = dyldaii->infoArrayCount;
                dataCnt = imageCount * sizeof(struct dyld_image_info);
                g_dii = (struct dyld_image_info *) malloc (dataCnt);
                g_imageCount = imageCount;
                readData = readProcessMemory(g_pid, dyldaii->infoArray, &dataCnt);
                if (!readData) { return;}

                struct dyld_image_info *dii = (struct dyld_image_info *) readData;

                // We don't need i anymore, anyway
                for (i = 0; i < imageCount; i++)
                    {
                        dataCnt = 1024;
                        char *imageName = readProcessMemory (g_pid, dii[i].imageFilePath, &dataCnt);
                        if (imageName) g_dii[i].imageFilePath = strdup(imageName);
                        else g_dii[i].imageFilePath = NULL;
                        g_dii[i].imageLoadAddress = dii[i].imageLoadAddress;
                    }

                break;
            }

        }
    }

}



 /* End 03/08/13 */
char *
behavior_to_text (vm_behavior_t b)
{

  switch (b)
    {
        case VM_BEHAVIOR_DEFAULT: return("default");
        case VM_BEHAVIOR_RANDOM:  return("random");
        case VM_BEHAVIOR_SEQUENTIAL: return("fwd-seq");
        case VM_BEHAVIOR_RSEQNTL: return("rev-seq");
        case VM_BEHAVIOR_WILLNEED: return("will-need");
        case VM_BEHAVIOR_DONTNEED: return("will-need");
        case VM_BEHAVIOR_FREE: return("free-nowb");
        case VM_BEHAVIOR_ZERO_WIRED_PAGES: return("zero-wire");
        case VM_BEHAVIOR_REUSABLE: return("reusable");
        case VM_BEHAVIOR_REUSE: return("reuse");
        case VM_BEHAVIOR_CAN_REUSE: return("canreuse");
        default: return ("?");
    }


}
char *
protection_bits_to_rwx (vm_prot_t p)
{

  // previous version of this somehow lost the "p&", always returning rwx..
  static char returned[4];

  returned[0] = (p &VM_PROT_READ    ? 'r' : '-');
  returned[1] = (p &VM_PROT_WRITE   ? 'w' : '-');
  returned[2] = (p & VM_PROT_EXECUTE ? 'x' : '-');
  returned[3] = '\0';

 // memory leak here. No biggy
  return (strdup(returned));

}

const char *
unparse_inheritance (vm_inherit_t i)
{
  switch (i)
    {
    case VM_INHERIT_SHARE:
      return "share";
    case VM_INHERIT_COPY:
      return "copy";
    case VM_INHERIT_NONE:
      return "none";
    default:
      return "???";
    }
}

macosx_debug_regions (task_t task, mach_vm_address_t address, int max)
{
  kern_return_t kret;

  mach_vm_address_t prev_address;
  /* @TODO: warning - potential overflow here - gotta fix this.. */
  vm_region_basic_info_data_t prev_info,info;
  mach_vm_size_t size, prev_size;

  mach_port_t object_name;
  mach_msg_type_number_t count;

  int nsubregions = 0;
  int num_printed = 0;

  count = VM_REGION_BASIC_INFO_COUNT_64;
  kret = mach_vm_region (task, &address, &size, VM_REGION_BASIC_INFO,
             (vm_region_info_t) &info, &count, &object_name);

  if (kret != KERN_SUCCESS)
    {
      printf ("mach_vm_region: Error %d - %s", kret, mach_error_string(kret));
      return;
    }
  memcpy (&prev_info, &info, sizeof (vm_region_basic_info_data_t));
  prev_address = address;
  prev_size = size;
  nsubregions = 1;

  for (;;)
    {
      int print = 0;
      int done = 0;

      address = prev_address + prev_size;

      /* Check to see if address space has wrapped around. */
      if (address == 0)
    { 
        print = done = 1;
    }

      if (!done)
        {
          // Even on iOS, we use VM_REGION_BASIC_INFO_COUNT_64. This works.

          count = VM_REGION_BASIC_INFO_COUNT_64;


          kret =
            mach_vm_region (task, &address, &size, VM_REGION_BASIC_INFO,
                          (vm_region_info_t) &info, &count, &object_name);

          if (kret != KERN_SUCCESS)
            {
        /* iOS 6 workaround - attempt to reget the task port to avoiD */
        /* "(ipc/send) invalid destination port" (1000003 or something) */
        task_for_pid(mach_task_self(),g_pid, &task);

        kret =
            mach_vm_region (task, &address, &size, VM_REGION_BASIC_INFO,
                              (vm_region_info_t) &info, &count, &object_name);


        }
       if (kret != KERN_SUCCESS)
    {
        fprintf (stderr,"mach_vm_region failed for address %p - Error: %x\n", address,(kret));
              size = 0;
    if (address >= 0x4000000) return;
              print = done = 1;
            }
        }

      if (address != prev_address + prev_size)
        print = 1;

      if ((info.protection != prev_info.protection)
          || (info.max_protection != prev_info.max_protection)
          || (info.inheritance != prev_info.inheritance)
          || (info.shared != prev_info.reserved)
          || (info.reserved != prev_info.reserved))
        print = 1;

      if (print)
        {
      int   print_size;
      char *print_size_unit;
          if (num_printed == 0)

            printf ("Region ");
          else
            printf ("   ... ");

       findListOfBinaries(task, prev_address, prev_size);
      /* Quick hack to show size of segment, which GDB does not */
      print_size = prev_size;
      if (print_size > 1024) { print_size /= 1024; print_size_unit = "K"; }
      if (print_size > 1024) { print_size /= 1024; print_size_unit = "M"; }
      if (print_size > 1024) { print_size /= 1024; print_size_unit = "G"; }
      /* End Quick hack */
          printf (" %p-%p [%d%s](%s/%s; %s, %s, %s) %s",
                           (prev_address),
                           (prev_address + prev_size),
               print_size,
               print_size_unit,
                           protection_bits_to_rwx (prev_info.protection),
                           protection_bits_to_rwx (prev_info.max_protection),
                           unparse_inheritance (prev_info.inheritance),
                           prev_info.shared ? "shared" : "private",
                           prev_info.reserved ? "reserved" : "not-reserved",
               behavior_to_text (prev_info.behavior));

          if (nsubregions > 1)
            printf (" (%d sub-regions)", nsubregions);

          printf ("\n");

          prev_address = address;
          prev_size = size;
          memcpy (&prev_info, &info, sizeof (vm_region_basic_info_data_t));
          nsubregions = 1;

          num_printed++;
        }
      else
        {
          prev_size += size;
          nsubregions++;
        }

      if ((max > 0) && (num_printed >= max))
    {
     printf ("Max %d num_printed %d\n", max, num_printed);
        done = 1;
    }

      if (done)
        break;
    }
}

void 
main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    struct vm_region_basic_info vmr;
    kern_return_t   rc;
    mach_port_t task;

    mach_vm_size_t  size = 8;
    vm_region_info_t    info = (vm_region_info_t) malloc(10000);
    mach_msg_type_number_t  info_count;
    mach_port_t     object_name;
    mach_vm_address_t   addr =1;
    int pid;

        if (!argv[1]) { printf ("Usage: %s <PID>\n"); exit (1);}
    pid = atoi(argv[1]);
    g_pid = pid; // req for iOS 6
    rc = task_for_pid(mach_task_self(),pid, &task);

    if (rc) { fprintf (stderr, "task_for_pid() failed with error %d - %s\n", rc, mach_error_string(rc)); exit(1); }
    printf ("RC %d - Task: %d\n",rc, task);


    macosx_debug_regions (task, addr, 1000);

    int i ;

    for ( i = 0; i < g_imageCount; i++)
    {
        printf("Image: %s loaded @%p\n",
            g_dii[i].imageFilePath, g_dii[i].imageLoadAddress);
    }
    printf("Done\n");


}
```

I also found [Julia Evans'](https://jvns.ca/blog/2018/01/26/mac-memory-maps/) blog post about recreating `vmmap` in Rust interesting and relevant to your question.

Another way you could do this is to call `system` with `vmmap PID > file` as the argument and then read the process mapping information from the file after `system` finishes.

Comment: Please credit Jonathan Levin, author of the book and the code.

Comment: @Kamil.S thank you for reminding me! I updated my post.